# Is there a way to detect near-rectangle in opencv?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I'm going to find the most look-like rectangles among shapes. The first image is the original image with shapes which possibly be rectangles but they are not. The green rectangles in the second image is what I want. So is there a way to do this with opencv? I've tried hough lines but the result's not good

The source image:
[image]

And what I want is to find out the most look-like rectangle among these shapes, like the rectangles in green.

What I want:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

A very simple approach is, after you have a rectangle bounding box around your shape, count the percentage of pixels inside the box which are white.

The higher the percentage of white pixels, the closest to a rectangle it is.

To get the bounding boxes you should take a look at either findContours from opencv, or some Blob extracting algorithm, you will find plenty of questions regarding those.

**Edit:**

Maybe you should first get the Minimum bounding rectangles of the shapes and then do this kind of heuristic:

- Shrink the rectangle dimensions until the white-pixel percentage inside the rectangle reaches some threshold defined by you (like 90% of white pixels inside the rectangle).

To get the Minimum bounding rectangle (the smallest rectangle which contains the whole shape), you might check this tutorial:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rects_circles/bounding_rects_circles.html

One thing that might also help is doing the difference of sizes from the minimum bounding rectangle and the maximum inner rectangle (the biggest rectangle you can fit inside the white shape). The less difference there is between those rectangle's properties (width, height, area, center coordinates) the closest is the shape to a rectangle.

Comment: findCountours will always cover all white pixels, but some white pixels are not part of the rectangle

Comment: It is not clear exactly which shapes you want to consider "rectangles". I can tell from your example that you are *not* looking for a minimum bounding rectangle (the smallest rectangle which contains the whole shape) but it is also not the maximum inner rectangle (the biggest rectangle you can fit inside the white shape).